# Environmental variables in Turbo

Tags: reactjs, next.js, environment-variables, monorepo, turbo

I am trying to use an environmental variable defined in my local `.env` file in one of my turbo packages, but it always comes up as `undefined`. I am using Turbo to manage my monorepo. The app is build in `Next.js/React/Typescript`.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
apps
--pages
----home.tsx // calling the Map component here
--...
--packages
----ui
------src
--------atoms
----------Map
------------Map.tsx // using the env variable here
----------...
--------...
------...
----...
--...
package.json
turbo.json
...
```

My `turbo.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://turbo.build/schema.json",
  "globalDependencies": ["**/.env.*local", ".env"],
  "globalEnv": ["NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN"],
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "outputs": ["dist/**", ".next/**"]
    },
    "dev": {
      "env": ["NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN"],
      "outputs": ["dist/**", ".next/**"],
      "cache": false
    },
    "lint": {
      "outputs": []
    }
  }
}
```

My top level `package.json`, the one for whole monorepo, looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "microforest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*",
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "dotenv -- turbo run build",
    "dev": "dotenv -- turbo run dev",
    "lint": "turbo run lint",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,tsx,md}\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv-cli": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint-config-custom": "*",
    "prettier": "latest",
    "turbo": "latest"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
  "packageManager": "npm@8.15.0"
}
```

My `Map.tsx` component looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactMapGL from "react-map-gl";

export const Map: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <ReactMapGL
      mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
    ></ReactMapGL>
  );
};
```

The `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN` variable always comes up as `undefined`. I've read the Turbo docs and tried all sorts of suggestions, but couldn't get it to work. Any idea what it might be?

Answer (score 1):

The prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC` is an environment variable that can be used in the browser in Next.js. In this context, the file Map.tsx is part of a UI package, and it is not considered a React component that is executed by the turbo run dev script. Therefore, the React component package may not be aware of environment variables. In my opinion, the component named Map should receive the `MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN` as a prop and pass it down from the environment variable injected in `pages/home.tsx`.

`apps/pages/home.tsx`

```
import { Map } from "ui";

export default Home() {
  return <Map mapBoxAccessToken={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN} />
}
```

`packages/ui/src/atoms/Map/Map.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactMapGL from "react-map-gl";

interface MapProps {
  mapBoxAccessToken: string;
}

export const Map: React.FC<MapProps> = ({ mapBoxAccessToken }) => {
  return (
    <ReactMapGL
      mapboxApiAccessToken={mapBoxAccessToken}
    ></ReactMapGL>
  );
};
```